# How to check a point is inside an ellipsoid with orientation?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, distance, computational-geometry

For an ellipsoid of the form

[image: formula]

with orientation vector [image: formula] and centre at point [image: formula], how to find whether a point [image: formula] is inside the ellipsoid or not?

An additional note that the geometry actually is with a=b (spheroid) and therefore one axis is sufficient to define orientation

Note: I see a similar question asked in the forum. But, it is about an ellipsoid at origin and without any arbitrary orientation and here both arbitrary position and orientation are considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find affine transform M that translates this ellipse in axis-oriented one (translation by -p and rotation to align orientation vector r and proper coordinate axis).
Then apply this transform to point p and check that p' lies inside axis-oriented ellipsoid, i.e.
`x^2/a^2+ y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2 <= 1`

Answer (score 1):

Create a coordinate system `E` with the center at `p` and with the long axis of the ellipse aligned with `r`. Create a matrix that can transform global coordinates to the coordinate system `E`. Then put the transformed coordinates into the ellipse equation.

Answer (score 1):

A center point *p* and an "orientation vector" *r* do not suffice to completely specify the position of the ellipsoid, there is one degree of freedom left. Your problem is indeterminate.

Comment: I have to add that the geometry actually is an oblate spheroid with a=b and therefore, I believe one axis is sufficient to define orientation.

Comment: Then follow the other answers. You can build a rotation matrix from the given orientation vector and any other (non-parallel) one, using the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process.

Answer (score 0):

If your vector r is a unit vector from the origin to the pole, then the test for whether a point q is in (or on) the ellipse is:

```
v = q-p;  // 3d vector difference
dot = v.r; // 3d dot product
f = dot*dot;  
g = v.v - f; // 3d dot product and scalar subtraction
return f/(b*b) + g/(a*a) <= 1
```

Note that if the ellipse was aligned so that r was the z unit vector, then the test above translates into the usual test for inclusion of a point in an ellipse.